ESP32-S3 does not print out to the serial monitor?
I am using PlatformIO and ESP32-S3 with ESP-IDF framework to code in my projects. I recently switched from Arduino framework to get better at this. I have found some examples from the documentation and tried to make a very basic serial transmitter code.
#include <string.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "esp_mac.h"
#include "esp_wifi.h"
#include "esp_event.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "lwip/err.h"
#include "lwip/sys.h"
#include "driver/uart.h"
#define BUF_SIZE (1024)
static const char *TAG = "UART";

void echo_task (void *arg) {
    const uart_port_t uart_num = UART_NUM_1;
    uart_config_t uart_config = {
         .baud_rate = 115200,
         .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
         .parity = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
         .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
         .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
         .rx_flow_ctrl_thresh = UART_SCLK_APB,
    };    
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_param_config(uart_num, &uart_config));
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_set_pin(uart_num, 17, 18, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE, UART_PIN_NO_CHANGE));
    QueueHandle_t uart_queue;
    ESP_ERROR_CHECK(uart_driver_install(uart_num, BUF_SIZE * 2, BUF_SIZE * 2, 10, &uart_queue, 0));
    char* test_str = "This is a test string.\n";
    while (1) {
         uart_write_bytes(uart_num, (const char *)test_str, strlen(test_str));
         vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS); // 1 second delay
    }
}

void app_main(void) {
    xTaskCreate(echo_task, "uart_echo_task", 4096, NULL, 10, NULL);
}

The problem is, this does not print out anything! I really do not see why, the pins are correct, the configurations are correct. I need another pair of eyes to see the problem.
I expected to transmit serial messages, but failed to do so.

It has to do with flow control I think.
Try Replacing:
rx_flow_ctrl_thresh = UART_SCLK_APB
(because you already disabled it the row above)
With:
.source_clk = UART_SCLK_APB
(will set your baud rate accordingly)

i changed it, but still no print out

I solved the problem, i changed uart port to UART_NUM_0, because that is the one that is connected to the usb port by default
